# Laravel - redirect from controller method not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this method in my `DocumentsController` and am trying to implement some simple permissions system, in that a user that is not an admin must have been assigned a branch and a department before adding, editing or deleting a `Document`.
Here is the code for the method

```
    /**
     * Check the credentials of the user that is not an admin
     * to add, modify a document
     */
    private function checkCredentials() {
        $user = auth()->user();
        // dd((!is_admin() && !$user->branch_id && !$user->department_id));
        if (!is_admin() && !$user->branch_id && !$user->department_id) {
            // dd(redirect()->route('documents'));
            return redirect()->route('documents')->with([
                'class' => 'alert-danger',
                'message' => 'Ask your administrator to assign you a branch and department first',
            ]);
        }
    }
```

And here is how am calling it in one of my controller methods that mapped to the route `Route::get('/documents/add', ['as' => 'documents.add', 'uses' => 'DocumentsController@create',]);`

```
public function create()
{
    $this->checkCredentials();

    ...

    return view('main/documents/create', $data);
}
```

Problem is the redirection is not working as it continues to display the form, even when the user has not yet been assigned a branch or department, that is when both the `branch_id` and `department_id` are both equal to `null`.

What could be the reason for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning the redirect from the controller, try this:

```
 /**
 * Check the credentials of the user that is not an admin
 * to add, modify a document
 */
private function checkCredentials() {
    $user = auth()->user();
    // dd((!is_admin() && !$user->branch_id && !$user->department_id));
    if (!is_admin() && !$user->branch_id && !$user->department_id) {
        // dd(redirect()->route('documents'));
      return false;
    }
}

public function create()
{
    if(!$this->checkCredentials()) {
        return redirect()->route('documents')->with([
            'class' => 'alert-danger',
            'message' => 'Ask your administrator to assign you a branch and department first',
        ]);
     }

    ...

    return view('main/documents/create', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you use authorization (gate/policy). https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization

Your code need to be

```
<?php

private function checkCredentials() {
    $user = auth()->user();
    if (!is_admin() && !$user->branch_id && !$user->department_id) {
        return redirect()->route('documents.add')->with([
            'class' => 'alert-danger',
            'message' => 'Ask your administrator to assign you a branch and department first',
        ]);
    }
}

public function create()
{
    $this->checkCredentials();

    //...

    return view('main/documents/create', compact('data'));
}
```